# why am i not getting the right answer for my if statements? also how do i find the average of all the inputs?

Tags: python, printing, average

For some reason, I am not getting the right number of fast females and fast males when i run this program. A fast female is a number less than -19 and a fast male is a number less than 15. Also, if anyone could suggest how to find the average of all the inputs combined?

```
#Write a program that categorizes user input

#Ask for user input
userInput=input("Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): ")

#Initialize variables
female=0
male=0
noRunner=0
fastFemale=0
fastMale=0
count=0

#Categorize input into male, female, fast female, and fast male
while userInput!="":
    count=count+1
    if userInput=="0":
        userInput=noRunner
        noRunner=noRunner+1
    if str(userInput).startswith("-"):
        userInput=female
        female=female+1
        if float(userInput) >= 19.0 and float(userInput) < 0.0:
            userInput=fastFemale
            fastFemale=fastFemale+1
    elif float(userInput) > 0.0:
        male=count-female-noRunner
        if float(userInput) <= 15.0 and float(userInput) > 0.0:
            userInput=fastMale
            fastMale=fastMale+1
    userInput=input("Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): ")

#Computations
total=male+female
noShow=noRunner

#Print statements
print()
print("Try-Out Report")
print("-"*40)
print("Total number of runners:", count-noShow)
print("Number of runners who didn't show:", noShow)
print("female", female)
print("male", male)
print("Average time for male runners:")
print("Average time for female runners:")
print("Average time for all runners:")
print("Fast female runners:", fastFemale)
print("Fast male runners:", fastMale)
```

Comment: List the numbers that are both greater than 19 and less than 0. Then look at your inputs. Also note that python variables are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As you get the inputs, build a sum then divide by the count

of course, initialize sum = 0 when you initialize count

Since you already remove the '-' sign you do not need to use abs so

```
sum += float(userval)

avg = sum/total
```

Note that you should use code such as

```
female += 1
```

rather than

```
female = female + 1
```

Note the problem here is that you change your input variable before you use it
this makes all future checks invalid. You also do not make the input positive before you check the value so that it will always be negative and thus never > 19 Changing it to string to look for the '-' is wrong, just check for < 0

Start with userInput which is already a float or an int

Check for negative value, then change to abs(userval) for the actual arithmetic within the Female category.

```
if str(userInput).startswith("-"):
    userInput=female # This messes up the next if
    female=female+1
    if float(userInput) >= 19.0 and float(userInput) < 0.0:
        userInput=fastFemale
        fastFemale=fastFemale+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if str(userInput).startswith("-"):
...
```

I'm flabbergasted by this. Use `userInput < 0` as you almost did on the following `elif`.

```
    ...
    userInput=female
    ...
```

When you do that, you just lost the userInput value.

Play with `input` in an interactive session and see how it works. There is no need for `float(userInput)`.

The code is really terrible. Try starting with a subset of the problem, for example just females, and try to understand what's going on, don't just try to get a result tweaking things randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make good use of pythons iterators and list-functions (`sum`, `len`) and -comprehensions.

Something like this:

```
def prompt():
    return input('Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): ')

data = [float(datum) for datum in iter(prompt, '')]

females = [-datum for datum in data if datum < 0.]
males = [datum for datum in data if datum > 0.]

print ('Males average: {}'.format(sum(males) / len(males)))
print ('Females average: {}'.format(sum(females) / len(females)))
print ('Fast males: {}'.format(sum(1 for male in males if male < 15.)))
```

---

Here an example interactive session:

```
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 0
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 0
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 12
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 14
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 18
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): -10
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): -11
Enter a time (negative for F, "" to quit): 
Males average: 14.666666666666666
Females average: 10.5
Fast males: 2
```

---

To categorize further you can do:

```
fastMales = [male for male in males if male < 15.]
fastFemales = [female for female in females if female < 19.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I abstracted out a Stats class which automatically tracks just the applicable values. It makes your code a bit longer but much simpler to follow:

```
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input   # Python 2.x
else:
    inp = input       # Python 3.x

def average(sum, num):
    return sum / (num or 1.)    # prevent div-by-0

class Stats:
    def __init__(self, title, filter_fn, neg=False):
        self.filter_fn = filter_fn
        self.neg = neg
        self.num = 0
        self.sum = 0.

    def add(self, item):
        if self.filter_fn(item):
            self.num += 1
            self.sum += -item if self.neg else item

    @property
    def avg(self):
        return average(self.sum, self.num)

female =      Stats("Female runners",      lambda x: x < 0.       , True)
fast_female = Stats("Fast female runners", lambda x: -19. < x < 0., True)
no_show =     Stats("No shows",            lambda x: x == 0.            )
fast_male =   Stats("Fast male runners",   lambda x: 0. < x < 15.       )
male =        Stats("Male runners",        lambda x: 0. < x             )

def main():
    while True:
        s = inp("Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): ")
        try:
            time = float(s)
            for stat in [female, fast_female, no_show, fast_male, male]:
                stat.add(time)
        except ValueError:
            break

    print("\nTryout Report\n----------------------------------------")

    print(
        "All runners: {:d} male + {:d} female = {:d}  ({:d} no-shows)"
        .format(male.num, female.num, male.num + female.num, no_show.num)
    )
    print(
        "Average times: {:0.3f} male, {:0.3f} female, {:0.3f} overall"
        .format(male.avg, female.avg, average(male.sum + female.sum, male.num + female.num))
    )
    print(
        "Fast runners: {:d} male + {:d} female = {:d}"
        .format(fast_male.num, fast_female.num, fast_male.num + fast_female.num)
    )

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which then runs like:

```
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): -20
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): -16
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): -12
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 0
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 0
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 12
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 14
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 16
Enter run time (negative for female, blank to quit): 

Tryout Report
----------------------------------------
All runners: 3 male + 3 female = 6  (2 no-shows)
Average times: 14.000 male, 16.000 female, 15.000 overall
Fast runners: 2 male + 2 female = 4
```